# Object returning from invoke java method handle

Tags: mule

I have send payload to Java method by using invoke tag. In that method I have create an Object `ItemBean` at set value to some attribute. In the end of method I have return `itemBean`.

The next step I want to do is invoke next method and receive Object `itemBean` that i have return from previous method. How can I do that?

This is my invoke config():

> invoke name="invokeme" object-ref="bu1" method="incomingHash"
>   methodArguments="#[payload]" methodArgumentTypes="java.util.HashMap"
>
> invoke name="invokeme2" object-ref="bu2" method="getInputPrice" > methodArguments="#SOME_THING" methodArgumentTypes="#SOME_THING"

I don't know what is object that returning from bu1 look like to config it at `methodArguments` in `invokeme2` and also not sure about  `methodArgumentTypes` too.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid your question is difficult to understand in its current state. I'm not exactly sure what you are asking. Typically, though, Mule works via a Message Processor architecture, which means that if you want to chain invocations, and pass data from the first invocation to the second, you do it through the Message, either as a  property of the message, or as the Message Body. Other options include flow or session variables, but those are more complex to handle. Anyway, I'll star your question. If you rewrite and make your question clearer, I'll do what I can to help.

Comment: It seems you're using the `invoke` message processor, which is great, but the configuration fragment in your question is broken and impossible to read: please fix it.

Comment: thank you for the response i cannot insert < before invoke in configuration fragment. I have solve this problem by do the same thing as i do in first invoke on the second invoke.However my test flow still not complete yet. If I have another question i'll ask in the new topic, Thank you again.